# Alternatives to Coldfusion Report Builder

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, pdf-generation, report

Anyone know of a good solution for pdf generation (preferably with a visual layout tool) that I can use from ColdFusion instead of the CF Report Builder?  It should be able to accept cfquery input.

Basically is there anything better than the crusty Adobe offering out there?

**EDIT**: With CF 11 and the "pixel-to-pixel" rendering of "most" CSS and HTML (see https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/PDF+Generation+in+ColdFusion+11), I wonder if anyone has attempted to do anything along the lines of 'normal reports', like page numbering, page breaks, etc. - the more traditional 8.5"x11" oriented features.  I'm a bit leery of trying to just do a drop-in replacement for CF Report Builder for this reason, knowing that HTML has no concept (in the browser) of discrete pages and page breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

obviously you can use cfdocument to what you want, but good luck getting it to look decent. however if you want to go down the route where you generate html using CFML and then *have that* outputted to a pdf, you can use [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). If you want a report builder type application, you can use [Jaspersoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio). BTW ACF's reporting engine is jasper reports under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

Jasper reports is an alternative that Railo folks use, you could give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  The closest thing I am aware of is DreamWeaver.  It's been a while but I believe with a Remote Development Service (RDS) password you can build a full dynamic report using the WYSIWYG design view. Add `CFDocument` tags around it and you have a pdf report. I believe using CFDocument with HTML / CSS is what most developers use in lieu of Report Builder.  I could be wrong but I've only seen it used once and judging by the lack of search results, I don't think it was received as well as it was hoped.

Of course you could always use crystal reports and continue using `CFReport` that way.
If you're using SQL Server you could get away with using SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS).